# Какие есть платформы для "хостинга" бэкенда

Tags: node.js, backend, hosting

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Чтобы приложение стало общедоступным его заливают на хостинг, для этого есть github, gitlub, heroku и тд. А как быть с бэкендом (сервером) на express.js, к примеру. Куда его обычно выкатыват, чтобы любой мог посылать на него запросы и это не было запущено на локальной машине?

Comment: Heroku, по-моему, и позволяет разместить сайт (или о чем речь?) на Node.js (Express). Облачные сервисы сейчас есть.

Comment: Если речь о самом сайте на `gitHub`, то это статичны сайт, можно реализовать даже переходы по страницам, но сервер там свой ни о каком `nodejs  c express-ОМ` не может быть и речи

Answer (score 0):

На Heroku можно развертывать в том числе и Node.js приложения - https://www.heroku.com/nodejs.

Также можно арендовать VDS на каком-либо из множества хостингов, в том числе и бесплатно (Amazon Web Services, Google Cloud Compute, Яндекс.Облако, Selectel и др.)